# Names for generic classes - how to avoid naming them just "object"? Use synonyms?

Tags: naming, object-oriented-design, abstraction, abstract-class

When programming, I often end up naming some generic class (think of an abstract base class for stuff you manage in your project) something like `FooObject`, `FooComponent` or `FooItem` (where `Foo` is an abreviation of project name). The problem is, that these names are used so often, they become meaningless - I mean, when I'm talking about an "object", no-one knows whether I mean "a subclass of `FooObject`", or an ordinary object.

I think that a good list of synonyms for "object", "component", "callback", "handler", "action" and so on would help, because we could just redefine these world on a per-project basis. You could even make up some totally nonsense word and define your meaning in documentation. I think it would be clearer than naming stuff "objects".

Here's what I mean by "nonsense" (taken from Alice in Wonderland):

> Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
>
> Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
>
> All mimsy were the borogoves,
>
> And the mome raths outgrabe.

Maybe you can have some nice words you use in such cases?

How do you deal with similar situations in your projects?

[ Related: [How to avoid general names for abstract classes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163847/how-to-avoid-general-names-for-abstract-classes) ]

Comment: Well, sure the top answer of the "related" question you linked to does not apply to your case as well? From what you wrote so far I tend to vote for closing your question as beeing a duplicate of that other question.

Comment: Well, this answer says to turn the base class to some separate classes, and while this is be a good idea in some cases, sometimes you have a hierarchy with clear is-a relations and you'd like to have the base class.

Comment: 'when I'm talking about an "object", no-one knows whether I mean "a subclass of FooObject", or an ordinary object.' - you can resolve this by saying 'object' when you mean an ordinary object, and 'subclass of FooObject' when you mean a subclass of FooObject.

Comment: Surely you'd want to to call a subclass of a `FooObject` a `foo` no?  I suffix all my abstract base classes with `base` so in my case the base class would be a `FooBase` so I can reasonably refer to all subclasses as `Foo`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the matter, Kent Beck said:

> "[...] The names should be short and punchy. However, to make the
>   names precise sometimes seems to require several words. A way out of
>   this dilemma is picking a strong metaphor for the computation. With a
>   metaphor in mind, even single words bring with them a rich web of
>   associations, connections, and implications. For example, in the
>   HotDraw drawing framework, my first name for an object in a drawing
>   was DrawingObject. Ward Cunningham came along with the typography
>   metaphor: a drawing is like a printed, laid-out page. Graphical items
>   on a page are figures, so the class became Figure. In the context of
>   the metaphor, Figure is simultaneously shorter, richer, and more
>   precise than DrawingObject."

(From Marcio Aguiar's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019/whats-the-best-approach-to-naming-classes)